# Yii2 User Logged Out After Redirect From Payment Getway

Tags: session, yii2, payumoney

Friends, I have integrated a payment method in Yii 2 Basic framework and the issue is when user do payment in payment getway and when they redirect from it then they lost the their session and they need to login again

anyone have any solution then guide me.

Comment: I would try checking if your session is set to send cookie with `SameSite=Strict`. Cookies with that settings are not send after redirects.

Comment: This happens only in google chrome, and I already set SameSite=Strict / Null and checked but its not working. :(